# cannot resolve listToStyles in vue-style-loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack

In project with Vue.JS (SFC file) bundled by Webpack, my configuration webpack seems to be in error because of vue-style-loader that cannot resolve listToStyles.js file.
Whereas this file exist into my directory node-modules 'vue-style-loader'

[image]

[image]

**My configuration Webpack is** :

```
const  path                         = require('path')
const  nodeExternals                = require('webpack-node-externals')
const { VueLoaderPlugin }           = require('vue-loader')


const buildDir          = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build')
const srcDir            = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src')
const srcEntryFile      = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'test', 'test-transpilling.js')

const mode = 'development'

const webpackConfig = [
{
        entry: srcEntryFile,

        output: {
            clean: true,
            path: buildDir,
            publicPath: './build/',
            filename: 'test-transpilling.js'
        },

        mode,
        devtool: 'eval',
        target: 'node',
        externals: [nodeExternals()],
        stats: 'verbose',

        node: {
            __dirname: false,
            __filename: false
        },

        resolve: {
            alias: {"@": srcDir},
            extensions: ['js'],
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    esModule: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }]
        },

        plugins: [
            new VueLoaderPlugin()
        ]
    },
]

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

*Why Webpack, babel or plugins can not resolve this ?*

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `extensions: ['js']` to `extensions: ['.js']` (note the `.`). That helped me solving the issue.